# My Android app crashes every time I run it

Tags: java, android

I made an android application that calculates quadratic equations. I built an apk and tested it on my phone and it did not work. Every time I run the app, it crashes even the button and the text fields don't show up. Only the window that contains the name of the app then it crashes.

here is the code:

```
package com.islamatabl.quadraticequationsfoa;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.*;

import java.lang.Math;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int duration = 5;
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();

                    EditText f1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText f2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    EditText f3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    TextView disp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                    TextView disp2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                    double a,b,c,root,inroot,x1,x2;
                    a = Double.parseDouble(f1.getText().toString());
                    b = Double.parseDouble(f2.getText().toString());
                    c = Double.parseDouble(f3.getText().toString());
                    inroot = Math.pow(b,2.0) - 2*a*c;
                    if (inroot<0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Math Error", duration).show();
                    }
                    else if (a==0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "a cannot be 0", duration).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    root = Math.sqrt(inroot);
                    x1 = (-b+root)/2*a;
                    x2 = (-b-root)/2*a;
                    if (x1==x2)
                    {
                        disp1.setText("X = " + String.valueOf(x1));
                        disp2.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        disp1.setText("X1 = " + String.valueOf(x1));
                        disp2.setText("X2 = " + String.valueOf(x2));
                    }
                    } 
                }



        });



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.islamatabl.quadraticequationsfoa.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="a:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="b:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="c:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="X1 ="
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="X2 ="
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Calculate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the logcat:**

```
04-19 17:18:54.312: D/AndroidRuntime(27681): Shutting down VM
04-19 17:18:54.312: W/dalvikvm(27681): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f862a0)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.islamatabl.quadraticequationsfoa/com.islamatabl.quadraticequationsfoa.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2081)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1217)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at com.islamatabl.quadraticequationsfoa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
04-19 17:18:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(27681):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please always add the stacktrace with your question.

Comment: Put all the views inside `fragment_main` and put all your stuff inside `onCreateView` in your fragment.

Comment: Please post your logcat. and implement all layout work in fragment xml

Comment: Actually, I did not run the app in a virtual machine because, my pc cannot run it. So, I do not have a log cat.

Comment: So then connect your phone to your pc and use the ddms tool to find the log.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you resolve a crash if you don't yourself know what's crashing.  You need to have a working set of developer tools -- logcat, Java-language debugger, etc.

Comment: I tried the ddms tool but it does not detect my device.

Comment: declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

initialize all these before setting the onclick listener and try it

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 EditText f1,f2,f3;
 Button calc;
 TextView disp1,disp2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                f1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                f2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                f3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                disp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                TextView disp2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
```

now set the onclick listener and try